# I made a function which covert decimal to binary. but it does not work

Tags: c, binary, integer, function-definition

```
#include <stdio.h>

void DectoBin(int *n);
int *p;
int position;

int main()
{    
   int num;
   printf("Input number : ");
   scanf("%d", &num);
   DectoBin(&num);

   for (int i = position - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
       printf("%d", p[i]);
   }
}
```

when launch this code, this code compile well...
but I have a error message 'zsh : segmentation fault'

```
void DectoBin(int *n)
{
    int binary[20] = { 0, };
    p = binary;

    while (1)
    {
        binary[position++] = *n % 2;
        *n = *n / 2;
        if (n == 0)
            break;
    }

    return;
}
```

so, What parts should be corrected to solve the problem??

Comment: Maybe correct the part where you attempt to access memory via a pointer that has not been initialized to point at valid memory.

Comment: For one thing, you use *n as an integer, but test "n" (which is its address, and will never be zero). So the while loop goes on indefinitely, eventually overflowing the buffer. Which, however, is orphaned as soon as you exit the function.

Comment: You shouldn't be using globals to communicate between functions.  But in any case, `DectoBin` sets the global `p` to the address of a local array.  So when it returns, `p` is no longer a valid pointer (since the array is no longer allocated).  It would probably be simplest to have the caller, i.e. `main`, pass the address of the result array to `DectoBin`.

Comment: You don't have to execute your program and hope it works. You can use a debugger to see variables, return values, memory, execute line by line etc.. You can also `printf()` values at any point.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who left the comments !

Answer (score 0):

I think the minimum change to make it **seem** to work is this:

```
// you use *n as an integer, but test "n" 
// (which is its address, and will never be zero).
// So the while loop goes on indefinitely, eventually overflowing the buffer. 

if (*n == 0)
    break;
```

A more serious problem is that the buffer is allocated backwards: you have the pointer *outside* the function and **the buffer is allocated on the stack inside the function**. So, as soon as the function exits, the buffer is no longer "legal". The data is *probably* still there (on my system, it is) and you might even be able to use it as if nothing was amiss. On a short program, and depending on your system, you might not notice that the code has become a time bomb.

You ought to estimate how much of a buffer you need (how many binary digits), then allocate memory on the heap, using `malloc()`, *check it worked*, and pass that memory to the function - which will allocate nothing - together with the allocated size, so it can ensure it doesn't overflow the buffer.

The function would then return how many digits to actually print.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

size_t DectoBin(size_t maxdigits, int *digits, int number);

int main() {
   int num;
   int *buffer;
   size_t maxdigits, position;

   printf("Input number : ");
   scanf("%d", &num);

   // Always check your inputs.
   if (num < 0) {
       printf("Negative numbers are not supported yet\n");
       return 1;
   }

   maxdigits = 1;

   {
       // Calculate how many digits are required. Could use ceiling of base-2 logarithm of num.
       int tmp = num;
       while (tmp > 0) {
           maxdigits ++;
           tmp /= 2;
       }
   }

   buffer = malloc(maxdigits * sizeof(int));
   if (NULL == buffer) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
       return 2;
   }

   position = DectoBin(maxdigits, buffer, num);

   for (size_t i = position; i > 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", buffer[i-1]);
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}

size_t DectoBin(size_t maxdigits, int *digits, int number) {
        size_t pos = 0;
        do {
                digits[pos++] = number % 2;
                number /= 2;
        } while (number && pos < maxdigits);
        return pos;
}
```

Comment: Why are not negative numbers supported yet?:)

Comment: *You ought to estimate how much of a buffer you need (how many binary digits), then allocate memory on the heap, using `malloc()`* That may be true in the most general case, but it's certainly overkill here!

Comment: @SteveSummit you're right, but I've learned the hard way that using magic sizes for buffers is a very bad habit to acquire.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow because the code would have to also ask the integer size, and that complicates things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is a typo

```
if (n == 0)
```

It seems you mean

```
if (*n == 0)
```

Though there is no any sense to accept a number indirectly through a pointer to it.

You are using the local array `binary` with automatic storage duration within the function `DectoBin`

```
void DectoBin(int *n)

{
int binary[20] = {
    0,
};

//...
```

that will not be alive after exiting the function. So the pointer `p` will have an invalid value.

Also it is unclear why you are using the magic number `20` in the array declaration. At least you should use the value of the expression `sizeof( int ) * CHAR_BIT`.

Also it is a bad idea to use global variables.

At Least you could declare the array within the function with the storage-class specifier `static` and return a pointer to the array from the function.

Pay attention to that for negative numbers you can get an incorrect result.

For example the function can be implemented the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

const char * DecToBin( int n )
{
    static char binary[CHAR_BIT * sizeof( int ) + 1 ];
    memset( binary, 0, sizeof( binary ) );

    unsigned int un = n;

    char *p = binary + sizeof( binary ) - 1;

    do
    {
        *--p = '0' + ( un & 1 );    
    } while ( un >>= 1 );

    return p;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%d -> %s\n", 123, DecToBin( 123 ) );
    printf( "%d -> %s\n", -123, DecToBin( -123 ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
123 -> 1111011
-123 -> 11111111111111111111111110000101
```

Comment: It's worth noting that bitwise division causes undefined behavior when `un` == `1`: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT34-C.+Do+not+shift+an+expression+by+a+negative+number+of+bits+or+by+greater+than+or+equal+to+the+number+of+bits+that+exist+in+the+operand

Comment: @LiamLoads un = 1; un >>= 1; is a valid code. There is no any problem.  So your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: "Do not shift an expression by a negative number of bits or by a number greater than or equal to the precision of the promoted left operand." Doesn't `1` have equal precision to `1`? Is this defined rule obsoleted by a new rule?

Comment: @LiamLoads Listen me. Your comments do not  make a sense relative to may answer. So please stop your spam. It will be better if you will pay attention to your bad code with undefined behavior.